# how to show second page as starting page on load of simple pager in gwt

Tags: java, gwt

I selected 5 th record from the second page of datagrid. After some modifications in the selected row i saved it And reloaded the datagrid.I want previous selected row to be selected after reloading also.

Any help can be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you still have the instance of your `DTO` that you were editing in your `DataGrid` you can do following:

```
// get the start index in the list
int selectedIndex = dataProvider.getList().indexOf(myObj); 
// set the visible range
dataGrid.setVisibleRange(selectedIndex,dataGrid.getVisibleItemCount());
// select the row
selectionModel().setSelected(myObj, true);  // select the row
```